# Operator of differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Let $A$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $k \geq 0$ an integer. Consider $\Omega^{k}(A)$ is the vector spaces of all $k$-forms in $A$. Now consider the linear operator
$$L: \Omega^{k}(A) \to \Omega^{n-k}$$

characterized by: if $\omega = dx_{i_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_{k}}$ then $L(\omega)$ is the $n-k$-form such that
$$\omega \wedge L(\omega) = dx_{1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{n}$$

My question is: consider $n = 2$, determine $L(fdx_{1} + gdx_{2})$, where $f$ and $g$ are real functions. How I proceed with the real functions?

Comment: I was thinking a little, is this operator really a function? Observe that $L(dx_{1})= dx_{1}+ dx_{2}$ also conforms to the definition, this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of $L$ you immediately get that $L(dx_1) = dx_2$ while $L(dx_2) = -dx_1$. Since $L$ is linear, you can simply pull the $f$ and $g$ out to get

$$ L(f dx_1 + gdx_2) = fdx_2 - gdx_1. $$

Comment: @Witzact why can I manipulate f and g this way? The real functions are the coefficients of vector space $\Omega^{k}(A)$?

Comment: Yes, $\Omega^k(A)$ is what is called a "module" over the ring of real-valued functions. What this means is that they are the "scalars". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map

Comment: @Witzact So, if $L$ is linear in the real vector space $\Omega^{k}(A)$ then $L$ is linear in the module? This is correct?

Comment: No, there are just two different types of linear. Linear over scalars and linear over functions. It depends on the context what is meant by linear.

Comment: Ok, but in my case, $L$ is linear in the real vector space, how can I proceed? Can you help me?

Comment: You can't really say anything if you just know that $L$ is linear in the vector space sense. If you can't pull out the functions, then I don't think you can actually calculate anything here.